# C# print A5 document created in calc (open office)

Tags: c#, printing, formatted-text

I use a calc document to print out information typed by hand several times a day in my office, so I decided to speed up the process by retrieving the data from mysql and auto-filling the form.
The problem is that I do not know how to set the printDocument in such a way that the printed result would be the same as the original calc document. 
The document should have different text sizes in specific positions on the paper, the paper has to be A5 and I need to insert a small .jpg representing my seal.
Is there any way to design the document somewhere and "connect" it with the printDocument object? Or should I create it from scratch - line by line? So far I only managed to create simple lines of text in the printPreviewControl, but not formatted and not where I wanted them to be...
If I preview the calc document in the web browser, take the source code and send it in a webbrowser control in my application, would that be easier? Would I be able to automate the printing process by programmatically choosing the correct settings? (printer and A5 size)

Comment: use crystal report,you can specific page size.

Comment: I am not familiar with crystal reports (amateur)...Can I use the design of my calc document in such a report?